# Magento2: How to trigger own javascript function in price change

Tags: magento2, javascript

In Magento you can define product price depending on e.g. product options. When the customer chooses product options, the price in product page is updated automatically.

I have added some code that displays installment amount and some other information, all depending on the price. Now when the product price changes, I should be able to the change the installment data as well.

How can I trigger my own javascript after the price has been changed?

Comment: Which page you want to add this functions ?

Comment: Product and category pages